# Isometries of a Connected Surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a connected surface, $p \in S$ and let $f,g:S \rightarrow S$ be two isometries.

Suppose that $f(p)=g(p)$ and $d_p f (X)= d_p g(X)$, for all $X \in T_pS$. I want to proof that $f=g$.

My guess: If we define $h:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and show that $d_x h =0$ for all $x \in S$, the result follows by connectedness of $S$. For that, we need $d_x f= d_xg$ for all $x \in S$ (and probably, here we use that $f$ and $g$ are isometries), but I do not know how to show it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this exercise on Do Carmo's? I think I remember seeing it there. Might need to use the exponential map.

Comment: Actually, I do not know, but probably. I saw this problem on a homework.I will try using the exponential map, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $h=g^{-1}\circ f$, $h$ is an isometry and $h$ fixes $p$ and $dh$ fixes the tangent plane $T_pS$, that is, $dh=id$.
Consider a small disk  neighborhood U of p such that every point $x\in U$ is connected with p by a geodesic. Suppose $h|_U\ne id$, there is a point $x\in U$, such that $x\ne h(x)=y\in U$. As an isometry $h$ maps geodesics to geodesics, so the geodesic connecting p and x is mapped to a geodesic connecting p and y. That is $h(\exp(tX))=\exp(tY)$ which implies $dh(X)=Y$ implies $X=Y$ a contradiction.
So $h|_U=id$, so the set W={$x\in S|h(x)=x\ and\ dh_x=id$} is open. W is obviously close and non-empty thus W=S since S is connected.

Comment: You don't need to assume that $S$ is complete.  A slight modification of this argument shows that the set of points $x\in S$ such that $h(x) = x$ is open in $S$. Since it is closed by continuity, connectedness implies that it is all of $S$.

Comment: @JackLee: Got your idea and modified the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually there's a gap in this argument. (It was also there in my suggestion, to be sure.) Your argument that $h|_U = \operatorname{id}_U$ was based on the assumption not only that $h(x) = x$ but also that $dh_p$ is the identity. So in fact, you should replace the set $W$ by $W' = \{x\in S: h(x)=x \text{ and } dh_x = \operatorname{id}\}$.

Comment: Excuse me, in the notation above what is $X$ and $Y$ in the equality: $h(exp(tX)) = exp(tY)$ ?

Comment: The tangent vector at $p$ of the two geodesics, respectively.